# Oracle report won't run in landscape

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

For some reason this report will not display in landscape orientation. I have changed the orientation parameter as well as the page layout, but this report will only display in a portrait view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the width and height properties of your Main Section so width is 11 and height is 8.5.